# Rest + Spring AOP + interface doesn't inject

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey, spring-aspects

I have a Spring AOP aspect used for logging, where a method can be included for logging by adding an annotation to it, like this:

```
@AspectLogging("do something")
public void doSomething() {
    ...
}
```

I've been using this on Spring beans and it's been working just fine. Now, I wanted to use it on a REST-service, but I ran into some problems. So, I have:

```
@Path("/path")
@Service
public class MyRestService {
    @Inject
    private Something something;

    @GET
    @AspectLogging("get some stuff")
    public Response getSomeStuff() {
        ...
    }
}
```

and this setup works just fine. The Rest-service that I'm trying to add the logging to now has an interface, and somehow that messes stuff up. As soon as I add the `@AspectLogging` annotation to one of the methods, no dependencies are injected in the bean, and also, the aspect is newer called!

I've tried adding an interface to the REST-service that works, and it gets the same error.

How can having an interface lead to this type of problems? The aspect-logger works on classes with interfaces elsewhere, seems it's only a problem when it's a REST-service..

Answer (score 2):

Ref the below Spring documentation (para 2) -

> To enable AspectJ annotation support in the Spring IoC container, you
>   only have to define an empty XML element aop:aspectj-autoproxy in your
>   bean configuration file. Then, Spring will automatically create
>   proxies for any of your beans that are matched by your AspectJ
>   aspects.
>
> For cases in which interfaces are not available or not used in an
>   application’s design, it’s possible to create proxies by relying on
>   CGLIB. To enable CGLIB, you need to set the attribute
>   proxy-targetclass= true in aop:aspectj-autoproxy.

In case your class implements an interface, a JDK dynamic proxy will be used. However if your class does not implement any interfaces then a CGLIB proxy will be created. You can achieve this `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`. Here is the sample

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AppConfig {

 @Bean
 public LoggingAspect logingAspect(){
    return new LoggingAspect();
 }
}



@Component
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

  ...
  ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion what you are actually trying to do is to add spring annotations to a class maintained by jersey. In the result you are receiving a proxy of proxy of proxy of somethng. I do not think so this is a good idea and this will work without any problems. I had a similar issue when I tried to implement bean based validation. For some reasons when there were @PahtParam and @Valid annotations in the same place validation annotations were not visible. My advice is to move your logging to a @Service layer instead of @Controller.

Comment: It might be something like that, though the rest-service already has @Inject annotations, so it will have spring-annotations in any case. But it might be that annotating methods messes stuff up..